# nest.js HttpModule.registerAsync() ,how to get the original request headers /cookies?

Tags: node.js, http, nestjs, interceptor, httpservice

In nest.js, Iam trying to forward cookies/headers from my orirginal request to next api in the call chain. api1->api2->api3 . any headers/cookies from api1 should be automatically included in other https service calls.

```
HttpModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    timeout: configService.get('HTTP_TIMEOUT'),
    maxRedirects: configService.get('HTTP_MAX_REDIRECTS'),
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
});
```